# NO permission given when install Django in virtual env in Debian -- Error when setting up Django

Tags: python, linux, mariadb, debian

So I am trying to write a guide for a class I am going to teach and because I am stupid I AM STUCK on trying to set up Debian Apache, Python, MariaDB and Django. SO I AM TRYING to install django with pop in a virtual environment but it doesn't want to install. Somehow I don't have permission even though I am an admin user and I used sudo. These permission things come up a lot in Debian and it makes using my computer hard. How do I fix this?

```
noachc@noach-21a4:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
mariadb-server is already the newest version (1:10.11.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
noachc@noach-21a4:~/Desktop$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user. If you've just installed MariaDB, and
haven't set the root password yet, you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Setting the root password or using the unix_socket ensures that nobody
can log into the MariaDB root user without the proper authorisation.

You already have your root account protected, so you can safely answer 'n'.

Switch to unix_socket authentication [Y/n] y
Enabled successfully!
Reloading privilege tables..
 ... Success!


You already have your root account protected, so you can safely answer 'n'.

Change the root password? [Y/n] y
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
Password updated successfully!
Reloading privilege tables..
 ... Success!


By default, a MariaDB installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone
to log into MariaDB without having to have a user account created for
them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation
go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving into a
production environment.

Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from 'localhost'.  This
ensures that someone cannot guess at the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

By default, MariaDB comes with a database named 'test' that anyone can
access.  This is also intended only for testing, and should be removed
before moving into a production environment.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
 - Dropping test database...
 ... Success!
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...

All done!  If you've completed all of the above steps, your MariaDB
installation should now be secure.

Thanks for using MariaDB!
noachc@noach-21a4:~/Desktop$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
noachc@noach-21a4:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-venv
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,200 B of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 python3-venv amd64 3.11.2-1+b1 [1,200 B]
Fetched 1,200 B in 0s (8,775 B/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package python3-venv.
(Reading database ... 417680 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-venv_3.11.2-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-venv (3.11.2-1+b1) ...
Setting up python3-venv (3.11.2-1+b1) ...
noachc@noach-21a4:~/Desktop$ cd ..
noachc@noach-21a4:~$ cd Home
bash: cd: Home: No such file or directory
noachc@noach-21a4:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Vaults  Videos
noachc@noach-21a4:~$ cd ..
noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ ls
noachc
noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ ls
noachc
noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ python3 -m venv myenv
Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myenv'
noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo python3 -m venv myenv
noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo source myenv/bin/activate
sudo: source: command not found
noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.6.0
  Using cached asgiref-3.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.3.1
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, asgiref, django
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse'
Check the permissions.
```

**

### Update

**. I did some digging and with the few IQ points I have I did the following:

```
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ ls /home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse
ls: cannot access '/home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse': No such file or directory
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ ls /home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
_distutils_hack  distutils-precedence.pth  pip  pip-23.0.1.dist-info  pkg_resources  setuptools  setuptools-66.1.1.dist-info
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ pip install sqlparse
Collecting sqlparse
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse'
Check the permissions.

(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ chmod +rwx /home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages': Operation not permitted
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
[sudo] password for noachc: 
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse
chmod: cannot access '/home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse': No such file or directory
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/myenv/lib/python3.11/
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/myenv/lib/
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/myenv/
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo chmod +rwx /home/
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ pip install sqlparse
Collecting sqlparse
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlparse'
Check the permissions.

(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo pip install sqlparse
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ sudo apt install pipx
```

It appears to have installed the package. What is going on and why is it doing this? Why would there be some "universal agreed upon" way to set this up and then when I try to do it something is very different and suddenly everything changes?

So I ran:

```
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home$ pipx ensurepath
Success! Added /home/noachc/.local/bin to the PATH environment variable.

Consider adding shell completions for pipx. Run 'pipx completions' for instructions.

You will need to open a new terminal or re-login for the PATH changes to take effect.

Otherwise pipx is ready to go! ✨  ✨
```

But when I try to start Django I once again get:

```
(myenv) noachc@noach-21a4:/home/mysite$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mysite/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mysite/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mysite/manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Once again I followed the legit Django guide and it lied to me. It told me to do something that was wrong. It made me think I Was setting up a correct thing and then what it told me was false. It have me wrong information. It didn't do what it was intended to convey. Why?